Получение аргумента из # Flask

Делаю авторизацию через YandexID и при редиректе он возращет в строке токен. Но передаёт не через ? а через #. Как получить оттуда?
@app.route('/auth/yandex/<arg>')
def yandexlogin_page(arg):
    print(arg)
    code = request.args.get('access_token')
    json = requests.get('https://login.yandex.ru/info?', headers={'Authorization': f'OAuth {code}'}).json()
    return jsonify(json)

текущий код не работает

Никак, якорь на сервер не передаётся в принципе

Никак, так как часть после '#' передается только странице. Хотя можно получить window.location, получить якорь и отправить серверу для дальнейших действий.
